# MvvmCross IMvxMessenger Subscription Firing Multiple Times for one Publish

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin, firebase-cloud-messaging, mvvmcross

I'm confused by this behavior with the IMvxMessenger.

I have a subscription that looks like this in the constructor of a viewmodel:

```
_updateToken = _messenger.SubscribeOnThreadPoolThread<PushNotificationReceivedMessage>(async (message) =>
        {
            await Reload();
        }, MvxReference.Weak);
```

The MvxMessage PushNotificationReceivedMessage is published in one spot, tied to a firebase event:

```
[Service]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" })]    
public class PulseFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService
{
    const string TAG = "PulseFirebaseMessagingService";
    public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)
    {
        Mvx.Resolve<IMvxMessenger>().Publish(new PushNotificationReceivedMessage(this));
    }
}
```

I am able to see that the message is published once, but that the subscription is invoked multiple times. Here's a call stack showing this happen:

```
>   0xE in Core.ViewModels.MainViewModel.Reload at Core\ViewModels\MainViewModel.cs:157,9   C#
0x38 in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start<Core.ViewModels.MainViewModel.<Reload>d__38> at /Users/builder/data/lanes/4468/f913a78a/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs:316,17    C#
0x2A in Core.ViewModels.MainViewModel.Reload    C#
0x15 in Core.ViewModels.MainViewModel.<-ctor<-ctor>b__37_0>d at Core\ViewModels\MainViewModel.cs:140,17 C#
0x38 in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncVoidMethodBuilder.Start<Core.ViewModels.MainViewModel.<<-ctor>b__37_0>d> at /Users/builder/data/lanes/4468/f913a78a/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs:84,17 C#
0x31 in Core.ViewModels.MainViewModel.<.ctor>b__37_0    C#
0x11 in MvvmCross.Plugins.Messenger.Subscriptions.WeakSubscription<Core.Messages.PushNotificationReceivedMessage>.  C#
```

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Thank you

Comment: Could it be that the View for the ViewModel has been navigated to more than once and the ViewModel not been cleaned up? So you are seeing messages being received for different instances of the ViewModel?

Comment: Which version of mvvmcross?

Comment: @Cheesebaron You are correct. For some reason I assumed that the default mvvmcross navigation handler was forcing single instances of vms